# MPI_Request - get the sender

Tags: mpi

I have an MPI program and MPI_Irecv function to receive a message from MPI_ANY_SOURCE. I need to see who the sender is, I guess from an MPI_Request *req. How do I get it ? I have tried req.MPI_SOURCE but it doesn't exist. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node31.html

```
Mpi_Status.MPI_SOURCE
```

Comment: +1: Note that the request must be completed in order to obtain a status object, and that after a request is completed the handle is set to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`, so you wouldn't be able to obtain the source from it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MPI C++ bindings, call "status.Get_source()".  This returns an integer.

Comment: stay away from MPI C++ bindings: they suck, hence deprecated http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi22-report/node328.htm. If you want C++ MPI use Boost.MPI